# Enabling CORS with .NET Core and Angular 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, angular6

I am trying to enable CORS within my ASP.NET Core API and allow passing cookies from my client application (Angular 6). However, whenever I attempt to hit an endpoint through my Angular application, I am receiving the following error:

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The
>   value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must
>   not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is
>   'include'

Within my Startup.cs file, I have CORS enabled under ConfigureServices like:

```
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                builder => builder
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowCredentials()
                .WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200"));
        });
```

and under Configure:

```
app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
```

In my Angular 6 application, I am calling the endpoint with a token like this:

```
this.http.get<T>(url, { headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'X-XSRF-TOKEN': token}), withCredentials: true });
```

The error is confusing because I am explicitly setting the allowed origins in .WithOrigins() within my .AddCors function, yet it's still saying there is only a wild card.

Comment: If you change `.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200"));` to `.AllowAnyOrigins()`, will this issue exist? Have you enabled `UseHttpsRedirection` in asp.net core?Share us the complete `Startup`, it would be helpful to share us a demo proejct.

Comment: The code that you provided looks fine and works on my machine.

Comment: @TaoZhou, that will not work because I need to pass a token / cookie up to the API and when you do this, you cannot allow any origin. You must specify the origin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is hosted on Azure.  Check the CORS settings in Azure AppService.  The configurations there will override any other Cors configuration even in the .net core middleware.

Comment: That seemed to be the case, thank you. We disabled CORS within Azure and it fixed the issue.

Comment: just searching for answers to respond to as this was the case with me, took me a while to figure it out. You can go to the App Service and search for CORS and it will request you to add accepted origins.

Answer (score 2):

within

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
```

after

```
services.AddMvc()
```

try

```
            services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowCredentials());
        });
```

then within

```
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
```

try

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
```

Once you do the above to your asp.net core api, you can test as shown below
[image]

if you can get the options request to the api to respond with the above headers, you have resolved the api CORS issue, then its time to move onto the angular 6 code.

Comment: I don't believe I can enable any origin because I am passing an XSRF token to my API.

Comment: My Angular application is getting those headers back for the preflight but I receive that error during the actual GET request

Comment: ASP,NET CORE 3.1, I need to remove AllowCredentials to work

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure out why app.UseCors wasn't effective on my Ubuntu server, regardless of the adjustments I made. The only workaround that proved successful was configuring it manually. I hope sharing this can save someone else the time and effort.
As a last resort and strictly for debugging purposes, you can add CORS headers directly in a middleware to see if they are respected. This is not recommended for production but can help pinpoint if the issue lies with the CORS middleware or elsewhere in your application or infrastructure.

```
    app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
    context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
    await next.Invoke();
});
```